# VideoJS - Safari 7.1, loading spinner does not go away on initial page load

Tags: javascript, video, safari, video.js, http-live-streaming

I'm implementing a video player using VideoJS.  Two key functions of this video player are:
a) If the user leaves the page, resume the video at that point when they come back or on refresh
b) Include HLS (h.264/mp4) support to provide better video quality depending on the connection.

The API for saving and retrieving a user's timestamp is already in place, and using the [excellent HLS plugin](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls), the video player works almost fine in all browsers as expected.  The following code is used to initialize the player and jump to the saved time:

```
            videojs.options.flash.swf = '../video-js/video-js.swf';
            var player = videojs(videoId);
            supportHLS = videojs.Hls.isSupported();
            player.ready(function() {

                [[event listeners for media controls]]
                this.on('seeked', function() { console.log('seeked');});
                this.on('seeking',function() { console.log('seeking');});
                    var PLAYER_LOADED = 'loadedmetadata';
                    if(!supportHLS) { PLAYER_LOADED = 'canplay';}
                    this.one(PLAYER_LOADED, function() {
                        this.one('canplay', function() {
                            this.play();
                        });
                        this.currentTime(savedPosition);

                        lastViewed = savedPosition;
                    });
            });
```

(Reason for the roundabout logic:  Chrome had issues with playing the video before the new data (after the seek) had loaded, which caused a number of problems with the data in the buffer.  Also, Safari 7.1 would break if you tried this during the 'loadedmetadata' event)

However, there's still one problem, specific to Safari.  The loading spinner doesn't always go away when you refresh the page.  Examining the logs and listeners seems to indicate that the 'seeking' and 'seeked' events fire at about the same time, but in different orders; the problem always arises whenever 'seeked' fires first, and never occurs when 'seeking' is first.  Furthermore, any seeking after the video is playing removes the spinner, so it has to be caused by the initial seek.

It's interesting that Safari supports HLS streaming natively, yet consistently causes the most problems with this player implementation.  This is the last Safari bug to iron out, but though it's small it still has a negative impact on user experience.

What causes Safari to fire the 'seeked' and 'seeking' events out of order like this?  What can I do to work around it, or is there a cleaner solution for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?